# php ClassName::staticFunction()->publicFunction() What is this doing?

Tags: php

I'm reading up on php design patterns, and I saw this code:

```
<?php
require_once("DB.php");

class DatabaseConnection
{
  public static function get()
  {
    static $db = null;
    if ( $db == null )
      $db = new DatabaseConnection();
    return $db;
  }

  private $_handle = null;

  private function __construct()
  {
    $dsn = 'mysql://root:password@localhost/photos';
    $this->_handle =& DB::Connect( $dsn, array() );
  }

  public function handle()
  {
    return $this->_handle;
  }
}

print( "Handle = ".DatabaseConnection::get()->handle()."\n" );
print( "Handle = ".DatabaseConnection::get()->handle()."\n" );
?>
```

I understand it all except the last two print statements. I've been messing around with it, but I don't understand the static function somehow calling a public non-static function.

I've notice I can do:

```
DatabaseConnection::get()->get()->get()->handle();
```

but I can't so something like:

```
DatabaseConnection::get()->handle()->get();
```

I just don't understand what this is doing, other than calling the get function then calling the handle function.

Comment: I see it now. The get() function is returning a object, and that object has a function called handle, and a function called get(). Which is why I was able to do Database::get()->get()->get()->handle(). Man do I feel dumb. I miss my dot notation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works because the static function returns a new object.  This type of construction is typically referred to as a Singleton, since it is attempting to enforce that only one instance of a `DatabaseConnection` is ever available.

Notice that the constructor is private, so you cannot explicitly call `new DatabaseConnection()` unless you are already inside the class.  Solutions utilizing a Singleton will have a property, initally null, that is then set to a non-null value upon object instantiation.  The 'getInstance' (or `get` in this case) method will only return a new object if the property is null.

Comment: I understand that much of it. I was mostly just wondering about the get()->handler() part of it. Does it have a name or a place in the manual that I can read up on it.

Comment: Not really, other than just looking at what is being returned.  In your two examples, the first one is calling `->handle()` method on a DBConnection object.  In the second one, you're attempting to call a `->get()` method on a simple string.  FYI I was a little surprised that PHP allows the syntax in the first example.

Comment: You had answered my question in your first sentence, sorry I didn't comprehend it.

Answer (score 1):

`DatabaseConnection::get()` creates an instance of `DatabaseConnection` and returns it.

So...

```
DatabaseConnection::get()->handle();
```

...could also be written as follows...

```
$db = DatabaseConnection::get();
$db->handle();
```

Comment: I get it now. get() is returning a object that has a function called handle. That makes more sense than what I was originally thinking.